# .xlsx file download success but can not open

Tags: html, angularjs, excel

i m trying to download and open a `.xlsx` file in my project by using `HTML` and `angularjs`.

i already put my `.xlsx` file in project folder and i want to download and open that file. so now my file are download successfully but can't open.

here is my `html` code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a class="btn btn-labeled btn-info" ng-href="BomItemTemplate.xlsx" download="" target="_self"><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-download fa-lg"></i></span><b>Download Template</b></a>
</div>
```

and i m facing this error when i open the file:

[image]

Comment: try to mention the file name and extension in the download tag ===> download="BomItemTemplate.xlsx"

Comment: yah..i add this..but still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Put Your `.xlsx` file in some public folder

public folder means that folder having a `CSS`, `img`, `JS`, etc...

now your html should be like :

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
     <a class="btn btn-labeled btn-info" href="public/contant/BomItemTemplate.xlsx" download="BomItemTemplate.xlsx" target="_self"><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-download fa-lg"></i></span><b>Download Template</b></a>
 </div>
```

This work for me! i hope this help to you !